# Proving $f(x) \geq f(x_{0}) + f'(x_{0}) (x-x_{0})$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in C^2(\Bbb R)$ and $f''(x) \geq 0 $ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

How do I prove that $$f(x) \geq f(x_{0}) + f'(x_{0})  (x-x_{0})$$ for all $x, x_{0}$ $\in \Bbb R$ ?

This was in our exam and I didn't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Taylor you have 
$$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(x-x_0)^2$$ $$ \stackrel{f''(\xi)\geq 0}{\geq} f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_0<x$. By MVT $f(x)-f(x_0)=f'(t)(x-x_0)$ for some $t \in (x_0,x)$. Since $f'' \geq 0$, $f'$ is increasing so $f(x)-f(x_0) \geq f'(x_0) (x-x_0)$. A similar argument works for $x<x_0$.

Comment: I like this proof as it's more elementary than Taylor and depends only on the fact that $f'$ is nondecreasing